# column names are getting truncated in sqlplus output ie excel file

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Hi I am doing a very basic manipulation ie trying to get the results of a sql query in an excel file. I am using the below format and I am getting the data but some column names are getting truncated.

```
SET PAGESIZE 40000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET MARKUP HTML ON
SET NUM 24
SPOOL file_name.xls

---- Execute your query

SPOOL OFF
SET MARKUP HTML OFF
SPOOL OFF
```

Comment: i also tried to increase the set num 24 to 50 but no change in the output

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the column length using the format specifier.

For example, 

`COL column-name for A50 (this is for text, syntax would differ for numeric columns)`

to print 50 characters, assuming the size of the longest value does not exceed 50.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your query. Please ignore my response.